# Why is execute() required before fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have the following piece of code:

```
$clicks = $statement->prepare($query);
$offers->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$clicks->execute();
$results = $clicks->fetchAll();
```

- The Query works fine
- The binding works fine

What actually makes me wonder, why I have to first execute() the query to can call fetchAll().
I've come to this solution/assumption since, execute() only returns true/false and without calling execute(), fetchAll() will not return anything.
Is this the normal way of doing that?

I've been working with PDO before, long time ago, so I can't quite remember how to deal with it properly.

Thank you very much

(I use PHP5.3, the above used code is PDO/PDOStatement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `SELECT * FROM myTable` is just a piece of text and you have to send it to the server first, which parses it etc, before you can `fetchAll()`. The reason that `fetchAll` doesn't automatically `execute()` is that `fetchAll` can be called twice, and you don't want to execute the query twice if you only have to do it once :)

It's also related to parameter binding etc. Parameters can change but you might still want to use the fetch functions on the original parameter value.

It's a design thing, which makes programming with PDO a lot easier. It just requires 1 more line of code :)

You could probably create a wrapper and make `fetchAll()` do both the execution and the fetch, but you're definitely going to run into trouble.

**edit**:
Another reason is that `execute()` actually takes an optional array of parameters which allows you to bind parameters. `$stmt -> execute(array($id));` would allow you to skip the `bindValue` calls.

Answer (score 1):

PDO `prepare()` uses [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), so yes: they must be prepared, then executed in order to have any results.  You can use [`query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) if you don't need to reuse the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because if the SQL was automatically executed as soon as a variable was bound, you wouldn't be able to bind multiple variables. Consequently you have to tell it when you are done binding by explicitly executing the statement.